# uib-dropdown position the list on top of button

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to set the position of the `uib-dropdown` list on top of the `button` if there is not enough space in the window to show the list at the bottom of the `button`.

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZSUzEgj1w5t5uK5DOtir?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Reason : dropdown event calls on window thats why it is always dropping down.

Solution : if you are using bootstrap just add "dropup" class to your dropdown menu

Comment: I am using uib-dropdown component.

Comment: In your plunker link i can see bootstrap as well

Comment: I have tried using "dropup", Only the icon on the button is changed, the list is still showing up below the button.